# Email from symfony to redirect to Vue file display a blank page

Tags: symfony, email, jwt, vuejs3

I try to go to a Vue file with a link into an email sent by symfony6.
Both servers are running without problem.
SF is https://localhost:8000
Vue is https://localhost:5173
I am using JWT, MongoDB

Code for Symfony controller (CheckTokenController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use App\Document\User;
use App\Service\JWTService;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

class CheckTokenController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/check_token/{token}', name: 'app_check_token')]
    public function index($token,
                            JWTService $jwt,
                            DocumentManager $dm): JsonResponse
    {

        // on implemente les differentes verifs du jwt token
        if($jwt->isValid($token) && !$jwt->isExpired($token) && $jwt->check($token, $this->getParameter('app.jwtsecret')))
        {
            // on recupere le payload
            $payload = $jwt->getPayload($token);

            // on recupere le user qui est defini ds le token
            $user = $dm->getRepository(User::class)->find($payload['user_id']);

            // on stocke les attributs de cet user ds 1 tableau
            // grace a la methode toArray definie ds le document
            $userData = $user ? $user->toArray() : null;

            // on met a jour l'attribut is_verified à true
            if ($user && $user->getIsVerified()== false) {
                $user->setIsVerified(true);
                $dm->flush();

                // Update the $userData array after updating the is_verified attribute
                $userData = $user->toArray();
            }

            // store les 3 parties du token, la jwtsecret, les attributs de ce user
            $data = [
                "route" => "check_token/{token}",
                "valeur_token" => $token,
                "isValid" => $jwt->isValid($token),
                "payload" => $jwt->getPayload($token),
                "isExpired" => $jwt->isExpired($token),
                "check" => $jwt->check($token, $this->getParameter('app.jwtsecret')),
                "user" => $userData
        ];
            return new JsonResponse(['valid' => true, 'message' => 'CONGRATULATIONS']);
        }
        return new JsonResponse(['valid' => false, 'message' => 'SORRY, you did not confirm your email']);
    }
}
```

Here the vue file (view03_check_token.vue):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const message = ref(null);
const route = useRoute();

onMounted(async () => {
  const token = route.params.token;
  console.log('Token:', token);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/check_token/${token}`);
    console.log('Response:', response);

    if (response.ok) {
      message.value = await response.json();
      console.log('Message:', message.value;
    } else {
      console.error("Erreur lors de la vérification du token");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="message_content">
    <h1 v-if="message">{{ message.message }}</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Chargement du message...</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.message_content {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  height: min(100vh, calc(16vw / 9));
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

Next is activation_email.html.twig. Includes different links to go to
https://localhost:5173/view03_check_token/tookkkkeeennnnn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Account Activation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello {{ user.nickname }},</h1>
    <p>Welcome to our platform!</p>
    <p>To enjoy authenticated area, you need to activate your account, please click the link below:</p>
    <p><a href="{{ absolute_url(path('app_check_token', {token: token})) }}">cliquez</a></p>
    <p>Or you can copy paste next to your web browser.</p>
    <p><a href="{{ absolute_url(path('app_check_token', {token: token})) }}">{{ absolute_url(path('app_check_token', {token: token})) }}</a></p>
    <p>Beware: this link will expire for 3 hours.</p>
    <p>the next ns amene a localhost:5173</p>
    <p><a href="https://localhost:5173/view03_check_token">Confirm your email</a></p>
    <!-- The rest of the email template remains the same -->
    <p><a href="https://localhost:5173/view03_check_token/{{ token }}">Confirm your email</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Next is router/index.ts:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    
    {
      path: "/view01",
      name: "view01",
      component: () => import("../views/view01.vue"),
    },

    {
      path: "/view02_subscribe",
      name: "view02_subscribe",
      component: () => import("../views/view02_subscribe.vue"),
    },

    {
      path: "/view03_check_token/:token",
      name: "view03_check_token",
      component: () => import("../views/view03_check_token.vue"),
      props: true,
    },

  ],
});

export default router;
```

https://localhost:8000/check_token/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjQ0OTZlMDYxMmExZjA1OTRlMGUzNjI1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjgyNTMzODk1LCJleHAiOjE2ODI1NDQ2OTV9.pjWaWytIe0lcxAUgWdcL8cGUqOkmRSe0jMD7XyuAueg
Displays the value: CONGRATULATIONS".

https://localhost:5173/view03_check_token/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjQ0OTZlMDYxMmExZjA1OTRlMGUzNjI1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjgyNTMzODk1LCJleHAiOjE2ODI1NDQ2OTV9.pjWaWytIe0lcxAUgWdcL8cGUqOkmRSe0jMD7XyuAueg
Displays blank page

No error into Console Firefox.